# discord.js TypeError: cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: discord.js

I have some code to get the attachments of messages in certain channels, and log the urls. This worked fine at first, but now I get the TypeError "cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined.

```
messageAttachments.push(message.attachments);
messageAttachments.forEach((element) => element.forEach(attachment_array =>console.log(attachment_array.url)));
```

I really have no idea why this is happening, between the fact that it didn't happen earlier, and that checking to make sure element is defined doesn't work.

Comment: Seems like the `attachments` property of the `message` object you are pushing into the array is undefined ...

Comment: @derpirscher If I do something like
`if (typeof message.attachments !== undefined)`, I still get the same error.

Comment: You use `forEach` two times. Once with `messageAttachments.forEach` and once with `element.forEach`. `messageAttachments` can't be undefined, because the `push` would fail and your code wouldn't reach the next line. So, based on the code you are showing us, at least one `element` in `messageAttachments` must be undefined. And the only `element` in `messageAttachments` is `message.attachments`. Thus either, this is undefined or the error is happening somewhere else or you are adding undefined elements elsewhere ...

Comment: And your typecheck is incorrect. `typeof` always returns a string. So you must check `if (typeof message.attachments !== 'undefined')`